# How to see from database side which INFA session has fired a query?

Tags: oracle, informatica, informatica-powercenter

When Informatica fires e.g. an update statement into the target database, how can I see from database side which Informatica session has fired this update clause? There must be some process_id or some other id running in database side which matches this query? I'm using Oracle database as a target db.

Answer (score 1):

Sessions are listed in v$session. STATUS = 'ACTIVE' for active sessions. Find value in column SQL_ID. To find SQL text look at v$SQL.